# Comic with aliens attacking in flying ships, protagonists finding mechs, glowing discs, a spherical spaceship, and an aquatic mech

Tags: story-identification, comics, mecha

I once had a short comic (maybe a promo of some sort) I read as a kid about aliens attacking in flying ships, and the protagonists had to find these mechs.

All I remember was that there were some sort of glowing discs, a spherical spaceship, and an aquatic mech found underwater.

On the back page, there was an image of one of the mechs as a painted model.

I have tried to find it online every now and then, but with no success…

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read the comic and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our [guide on asking identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/7957).

Comment: Also, please consider [registering](/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827) to more features of the site. As an unregistered user, you can’t vote, and you’ll lose access to your account if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Once you lose access, you won’t be able to accept answers or edit posts (without requiring other users’ approval) that you made under the unregistered account. Registering an account is easy, and it will allow you to participate more fully in our community.